# find key with least value in dictionary python consisting of values in string format

Tags: python

i have a dictionary

```
d = {1:'1.112',2:'3.084',3:'6.2',4:'not_valid',5:'0.235'}
```

i want to find the key with the least value in my dictionary.

i could get it easily using `min(d, key=d.get)` ,if all my values were int or float.

But the data type of my values is `str`

i want to ignore the value `'not_valid'` and find the minimum number i.e `0.235`
and the key corresponding to that = `5`

Comment: What if different keys have the same value?

Comment: @S.M.Styvane then pick any one of the keys. This would be considered as an outlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own function that attempts a conversion to `float`, and if it fails (like in the case of 'not_valid') returns `math.nan`, then use the same technique you were trying before by passing that function to `min` as the `key`

```
import math

def to_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return math.nan

>>> min(d, key=lambda i: to_float(d[i]))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible way to solve it is:

```
def custom_key(k):
  if d[k] == 'not_valid':
    return float('inf')
  return float(d[k])
```

so :

```
>>> min(d, key=custom_key)
5
```